# Redirect URL when there is a specific word in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to redirect my URL to the home page or another page when there is a specific word in the URL.
I found a lot of solutions on StackOverflow but my question is slightly different.

I am using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} testimonial
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

to redirect pages like "xyz.com/testimonial/sometext" to the home page if URL contains a word testimonial.
The code above is doing it nicely but the problem is that it redirects my another page which is "xyz.com/testimonials/".

My question is how to prevent code above to redirecting me to the home page when the URL is "xyz.com/testimonials/"

Thanks in advance and I am sorry if I made any mistake in posting question.

Comment: Well if you only need to redirect URLs of the form `/testimonial/sometext`, then you could simply include the slash after `testimonial` in what you check the request URI for …

Comment: Awesome @misorude. your answer resolved the issue and I am amazed at how simple the solution was. Thank you for your kind help.